# Excel macro VBA cannot read windows 10 environment variable

Tags: excel, vba, environment-variables

As shown in the following diagram, my computer has an new added environment variable `CMIS_HOME_DB2` with value `D:\kei_D\CMIS_DEV\CMIS\Source\DEVB_CMIS`, but in excel VBA, when I use:

```
strXLS = Environ("CMIS_HOME_DB2") & "\export\perf.txt"
```

`CMIS_HOME_DB2` cannot be read. Any reason?

[image: excel macro]

Comment: Silly question, but did you try to turn it on and off again (proper restart, either reboot or hold shift when pressing shutdown). What do you get when you type `? Environ("CMIS_HOME_DB2")` into your immediate window?

Comment: Try `For i = 1 To 100: Debug.Print Environ(i): Next` in the immediate page and copy and paste the name from the list.  It might be a character code issue.